# How to display the array based on the date and it has a limit based on the date in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to display the array based on the date and it has a limit to the date if the same array have same date.

for example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2mftp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
const arr = [
 0: [{
  name: 'Mike',
  date: '2020-02-14 09:09:02'
 },{
  name: 'Jes',
  date: '2020-02-13 09:09:02'
 },
 {
  name: 'Min',
  date: '2020-02-13 10:09:02'
 },
 {
  name: 'Tel',
  date: '2020-02-13 10:20:02'
 }],
 1: [{
  name: 'Fin',
  date: '2020-02-13 09:09:02'
 },
 {
  name: 'Jake',
  date: '2020-02-13 10:09:02'
 },
 {
  name: 'Trish',
  date: '2020-02-13 10:20:02'
 },
 {
  name: 'Tim',
  date: '2020-02-12 10:20:02'
 }]
]
```

expected output should be. if the data date is not equal to the another array it should not displayed. it should remove if this array data1 has no date based on the another array data2 then it will not display

```
arr = [
0: [{
      name: 'Jes',
      date: '2020-02-13 09:09:02'
     },
     {
      name: 'Min',
      date: '2020-02-13 10:09:02'
     },
     {
      name: 'Tel',
      date: '2020-02-13 10:20:02'
     }],
     1: [{
      name: 'Fin',
      date: '2020-02-13 09:09:02'
     },
     {
      name: 'Jake',
      date: '2020-02-13 10:09:02'
     },
     {
      name: 'Trish',
      date: '2020-02-13 10:20:02'
     }]
    ]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  You need to provide a sample of code which attempts to solve your problem.

Comment: @Paul ok sir...

Comment: @MisterJojo but if it's not equal to the other array it shouldn't be displayed. it try to create a code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q2mftp?file=src/app/app.component.ts here's the code

Comment: `const arr = [  0: [{   name: 'Mike',...` is syntax invalid

Comment: I suggest reading up on [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Would love to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this:

```js
const
  ArrayTest
    = [ [ { name: 'Mike',  date: '2020-02-14 09:09:02' } 
        , { name: 'Jes',   date: '2020-02-13 09:09:02' } 
        , { name: 'Min',   date: '2020-02-13 10:09:02' } 
        , { name: 'Tel',   date: '2020-02-13 10:20:02' } 
        ] 
      , [ { name: 'Fin',   date: '2020-02-13 09:09:02' } 
        , { name: 'Jake',  date: '2020-02-13 10:09:02' } 
        , { name: 'Trish', date: '2020-02-13 10:20:02' } 
        , { name: 'Tim',   date: '2020-02-12 10:20:02' } 
      ] ]
    ,
  getYMD
    = el => el.date.split(' ')[0]
    ,
  commons
    = ArrayTest
        .map(elm=>[...new Set(elm.map(getYMD))])
        .reduce((a,c)=>a.filter(x=>c.includes(x)))
    ,
  resTarget
    = ArrayTest
        .map(elm=>elm.filter(sub=>commons.includes(getYMD(sub))))
    ;
console.log( JSON.stringify(resTarget,0,2 ))
  ;
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Property 'flat' does not exist on type 'string[]'

Comment: can you create an example in stackblitz\

Comment: @Panda ? for what ? the snippet code here test and show everything!